# Bash/Perl Multiline Regex Issue

Tags: regex, bash, perl

Trying to apply some formatting a some files in a bash script and after a lot of web searches and trial / error, I came up with this using perl regexes as I need it be Mac / Linux compatible:

```
#!/bin/sh
FILES="$(find . -type f -name '*.php')"
for FILE in $FILES
do
    # 1. Add blank line after "global $XYZ" calls
    RET=$(perl -i -pe 's/^(\s*)global(\s)(.+);(\s*)$/$1global$2$3;\n\n\n/' $FILE)

    # 2. Add blank line before "$query" calls
    RET=$(perl -i -pe 's/\$query(\s+)(\.?=)/\$query $2/' $FILE)
    RET=$(perl -i -pe 's/^(\s*)\$query (\.?=)/\n$1\$query $2/' $FILE)

    # 3. Add blank line before "$ret" calls
    RET=$(perl -i -pe 's/\$ret(\s+)=/\$ret =/' $FILE)
    RET=$(perl -i -pe 's/^(\s*)\$ret =/\n$1\$ret =/' $FILE)

    # 4. Add blank line after single line "$ret" calls
    RET=$(perl -i -pe 's/^(\s*)\$ret(.+);(\s*)$/$1\$ret$2;\n/' $FILE)

    # 5. Add blank line before "list" calls
    RET=$(perl -i -pe 's/^(\s*)list\(/\n$1list(/' $FILE)

    # 6. Add blank line after single line "list" calls
    RET=$(perl -i -pe 's/^(\s*)list(.+);(\s*)$/$1list$2;\n/' $FILE)

    # 7. Add blank line after closing braces
    RET=$(perl -i -pe 's/^(\s*)\}(\s*)$/$1\}$2\n/' $FILE)

    # 8. Add blank line after closing multiline statements
    RET=$(perl -i -pe 's/^(\s*)\);(\s*)$/$1\);$2\n/' $FILE)

    # 9. Remove superflous blank lines
    RET=$(perl -i -0pe 's/(\n\s*){2,}(\n\s*)/\n$2/gs' $FILE)
    RET=$(perl -i -0pe 's/(\s*)(\/\/.+)(\n\s*){2,}$/$1$2\n/gs' $FILE)
done
```

It seems to generally work but the very last regex does not seems to kick in although I have tested it with online regex testers and it matches there.

I suspect it may be related to the /g modifier in the previous run but not sure.

Basically, I want to fix instances of blank lines after single line comments so that ...

```
  // Some Comment

  $ret = "XYZ";
```

is shown as ...

```
  // Some Comment
  $ret = "XYZ";
```

As said, the whole thing just works as if the regex is not there.

Comment: Note that you should add `m` modifier to the last regexp to match line endings using `$`. If not, `$` will only match end of string.

Comment: `.+` is greedy. Also, rearrange so `\n` is after whitespace.  Try: `s/(\s*)(\/\/.+?\n)(\s*\n)/$1$2/gs`

Comment: @HåkonHægland. Thanks but it is not picking up anything

Comment: @jhnc. Very close. Fixes the instances I have issues with but also doing more. I.E., it is extending to other stuff

Comment: @Dayo See the comment of @jhnc, I think the problem is that `.+` is gobbling up new lines characters

Comment: This should be *one* `perl` script instead of running `perl` 12 times per file.

Comment: @chepner. This is a part of a larger bash script.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Write it as one perl script, and call that once - and I don't even mean once per file. Let it read the list once through and be done.

Comment: @Dayo Then this *portion*, if not necessarily the entire `bash` script, should be a single `perl` script.

Comment: @chepner Would appreciate pointers on how to do this. I.E., How to embed section of perl within the bash script

Comment: You don't; you write a perl script, then call it. The entire shell loop gets replaced with `perl myScript.pl "${FILES[@]}"`.

Comment: @jhnc. Managed to amend your regex to get it working. Ended up with `s/(\s*)(\/\/[^\n]+\n)(\s*\n)/$1$2/gs`. Please make a proper answer so I can accept.

Comment: @chepner. I have a few more to add so I might look into your suggestion.

Comment: Tip: `-0` doesn't actually enable slurp mode. Use `-0777` for that.

Comment: @ikegami. I find that for some reason, I get the results I want with the format I put above and that `-0777` does not do what I intend. Confess i don't know that much on the subject but I have spent several days in getting to what seems to work.

Comment: `-0` means `$/ = \0;`, which means "lines are terminated by NUL". If you have no NULs in the file, you end up with the desired effect of reading the entire file. `-0777`, OTOH, means `$/ = undef;`, which means "read the entire file".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can write the script as a single `perl` script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;

my @files = File::Find::Rule->new->file->name('*.php')->in('.');
@ARGV = @files;
$^I = '.bak';  # suffix of backup file, see perldoc perlvar
while (<<>>) {
    s/^(\s*)global(\s)(.+);(\s*)$/$1global$2$3;\n\n\n/;
    s/\$query(\s+)(\.?=)/\$query $2/;
    s/^(\s*)\$query (\.?=)/\n$1\$query $2/;
    s/\$ret(\s+)=/\$ret =/;
    s/^(\s*)\$ret =/\n$1\$ret =/;
    s/^(\s*)\$ret(.+);(\s*)$/$1\$ret$2;\n/;
    s/^(\s*)list\(/\n$1list(/;
    s/^(\s*)list(.+);(\s*)$/$1list$2;\n/;
    s/^(\s*)\}(\s*)$/$1\}$2\n/;
    s/^(\s*)\);(\s*)$/$1\);$2\n/;
    print;
}
@ARGV = @files;
local $/ = undef; # Read the whole file
while (<<>>) {
    s/(\n\s*){2,}(\n\s*)/\n$2/gs;
    s/^(\s*)(\/\/.+?)(\n\s*){2,}/$1$2\n/gs;
    print;
}
```

Comment: perhaps `<<>>` instead of `<>` to avoid the security hole

Comment: @jhnc Good catch, yes use `<<>>` to avoid use of the 2-argument `open` on the files which allows filenames like: `rm -rfv *|`

Comment: What does `<<>>` do? What is funny with Perl is that if I search for `perl "<<>>"` in Google I don't find any relevant answers within the first 10 results :(

Comment: @nowox See [perldoc perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators)

Comment: @HåkonHægland. Is it possible to have multiple extensions in the finder?

Comment: @Dayo Yes, you could simply add them as arguments to the `name()` method. For example:  `name('*.php', '*.html')`. See the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) for more information